# how to combine two columns from different tables and get single column

Tags: plsql

I have two tables table A and table B .

Table A contain column colA which contains values (1,3,5,7)

Table B contain column colB which contains values (2,4,6,8)

My query is how can i combine these two tables and get one column with output (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

I am using oracle 10g

Answer (score 6):

Maybe:

```
SELECT colA FROM A
 UNION ALL
SELECT colB FROM B
```

If you care about order and unicity:

```
SELECT colA FROM A
 UNION
SELECT colB FROM B
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be avail...

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT colA AS TEMP_COL FROM A  
UNION 
SELECT colB AS TEMP_COL FROM B 
)
ORDER BY TEMP_COL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with A as (
            select 1 as cola from dual
            union all 
            select 2 as cola from dual 
            union all 
            select 3 as cola from dual
           ),
     B as (
            select 4 as colb from dual 
            union all 
            select 5 as colb from dual 
            union all 
            select 6 as colb from dual
            )
```

select substr(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(colab, ','),2) col_list 
from 
   ( 
    select colab,
           count(*) over (partition by 1) as cnt,
           ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( partition by 1 order by colab) seq 
    from 
        ( 
         select cola as colab from A 
         union all 
         select colb as colab from B
         )
    ) 
where cnt = seq
start with seq = 1 
connect by prior seq + 1 = seq

or

```
select 
   rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (el, colab || ',')).extract ('//text()'), ',') col_list
from 
        ( 
         select cola as colab from A 
         union all 
         select colb as colab from B
         )
```

Regards..

Answer (score -1):

For 10g, try -

`SELECT WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(
 SELECT Cola as Colab FROM A
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Colb AS Colab FROM B
) FROM DUAL;`